# How to open a PSD file stored on the SD card?

Tags: android

I am developing an application. The application needs to open a [PSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop#File_format) file within the application.

I was able to open all other types of files, like [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), text, [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format), etc., but I was not able to open a PSD file.

Is there a method for this?

Comment: any idea or any to do it

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Find an application capable of viewing PSD files on Android. This topic has nothing to do with Stack Overflow.

Step #2: Try `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with the appropriate MIME type. Unfortunately, there seem to be several possible MIME types for PSD files (`image/psd`, `image/photoshop`, `image/vnd.adobe.photoshop`, `image/x-photoshop`, `application/photoshop`, etc.). If you cannot find one that works, contact the developers of the application to see if they indeed support `ACTION_VIEW` `Intents`, as they might not, and if they do, what MIME type they use.